# Missing 'Page Attributes' in page edit

Tags: pages, admin, page-template

Im missing Page Attributes from page edit screen. I have searched and not found any solution. Anybody with some ideas?

Comment: did you hide it in screen options?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that easy. It's not visible there either.

Comment: are you using the block editor, or the classic editor? And are you editing a page, or a custom post type? I assume you've tried this as an administrator, and that you've physically verified that there are valid page templates in the theme?

Comment: They are using the classic editor and it is a standard page type and there are valid page templates in the theme. The custom page template are coded by the clients former agency.